# Salvar variáveis de um select e manter o valor no php

Tags: php, html5

Estou criando um jogo em php, onde você terá várias e várias decisões para fazer. O problema é que o jeito que fiz de funcionar, foi separando o comando de decisão, colocando ele na última linha com um `<input type="text">` e um botão de enviar. Fiz um if para cada decisão onde ele lê a variável `$decision`.

```
if(isset($_GET['decision']))
{

$decision=$_GET['decision'];
if($decision==0)
{   echo'<br>   <br><b>Você digita o número de cada ação para jogar.O local está vazio, com um armário e uma escrivaninha, ambos vazios.<br> Você se senta na cama de decide o que irá fazer.<br>   1 - Investigar os quartos<br>   2 - Descer um andar(taverna)<br>    3 - Sair da taverna(cidade)<br> ';  }
if ($decision==1)
{       echo'<br>Você sai do quarto e olha em volta. você enxerga 4 quartos e uma escada.<br>           4- Entrar no quarto 1<br>           5-Entrar no quarto 2<br>            6-Entrar no quarto 3<br>            7-Entrar no quarto 4<br>            2-Ir para a taverna(descer a escada)        ';  }
if ($decision==2)
{   
    echo'<br>Você vai até a taverna. o dono está servindo as pessoas (Senão ele não ganharia dinheiro já que só ele trabalha na taverna),       <br>Tem um bardo tocando música próximo á entrada da taverna.<br> As pessoas sentadas, estão com uma expressão séria, a maioria possui algum ferimento ou hematoma, com a exceção de um rapaz encapuzado no fundo           <br>1- Ir para os quartos<br>           3-Ir para a cidade<br>      8-Falar com o dono<br>          9-Falar com o arauto<br>            10-Falar com um cara de capuz no fundo da taverna<br>';     
}
```

O código acima é o que vai ler as decisões  e mostrá-las na tela, ele pega o valor de `$decision` através de:

```
 if(isset($_GET['n1']) || isset($_GET['decision']) || $gamestart==0)
{
<input type="hidden" name="decision" value="'.$decision.'">
 <br><br>Ação: <input type="text" name="decision"><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>';
}
```

Eu tentei colocar um `<input type="select">` com as opções (assim seria impossível trapacear no jogo) dentro de cada if, mas ele acaba por não mostrar nada. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer os selects funcionarem, ou eu vou ter que fazer com esse input mesmo.

Comment: Você quer  mostrar no select option, se sim seria `<select><option value="">Texto</select>`

Comment: eu tentei isso, e com os values de cada número diferente. Mas não funcionou, o programa não salva as informações e exibe as variáveis como nulas

Comment: Como você está enviando o valor GET?

Comment: estou usando em um else no final do código `<form action="?" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="decision" value="'.$decision.'">
     <br><br>Ação: <input type="text" name="decision"><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>  `

Comment: Nao estou vendo o inicio do form

Comment: action é interrrogação mesmo?

Comment: Sim, em outra pergunta que fiz, isso ajudava a pegar a variável

Comment: E se você redirecionar para a propria pagina?

Comment: Você diz com um `a=href`? como isso funcionaria?

Comment: Não. No action colocar o `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"`

Comment: Eu não teria como testar isso agora, pois estou usando o php helper, ele não permite com comandos em relação á criação de servidores e sessões. Mas quando eu conseguir, eu te aviso

Comment: Beleza, então!.